# How secure is data on an external drive protected with Windows 7 BitLocker?

Tags: encryption, windows-7

Just curious, say, not considering the strength of my password (let's assume it's very strong, something like "j*ds73hSoe93%KE4") how secure is my data on an external drive that is protected with a BitLocker feature of Windows 7 Ultimate?

Comment: As long as the password can't be guessed it's essentially uncrackable at the moment. Having said that, this question is better suited for SuperUser.

Comment: What kind of attack are you referring to?  For example, there might be a difference between someone just stealing the drive and taking it home to fiddle with versus someone inserting malware into your system to potentially break in that way. Not that I can answer either way, but the question seems a bit vague.

Comment: Sorry, I should've posted it there... As the attack goes, I mean protecting my data (files) from being stolen.